# Add method to Struct Property of pointer type

Tags: go, tiedot

I have this struct:

```
type AppContext struct {
    DB                *db.DB
    Properties        *db.Col
}
```

`Properties` of the Type `*db.Col` is a [Tiedot](https://github.com/HouzuoGuo/tiedot) Collection.

The problem I have is that for my buffering system I want to be able to fetch name of the collection. Weirdly enough the default deployment of the library can't do it.

When I instantiate the `AppContext` like so:

```
App = AppContext{}
```

..and then do:

```
App.DB.Create("Properties")
App.Properties = App.DB.Use("Properties")
```

I want to add an instance method, but it doesn't allow me to:

```
func (dbCol App.Properties) ColName() string {
    return "Properties"
}
```

Any idea how I could accomplish this or maybe extend Tiedot in a smarter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that such extension is possible in Go. However, I sure that the problem can be solved in some other way. For example, you can create structure that holds the collection and its name:

```
type Collection struct {
  Col *tiedot.Col
  Name string
}
```

and initialise it

```
App.Properties = Collection{App.DB.Use("Properties"), "Properties"}
```

Comment: Elegant :-). Luckily my code is structured to handle this change. I will implement it tonight! Thanks :)